# Formula field with Image in List Views in Lightning Experience

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-apps, lightning-design-system

Currently, Status of the Case list view to get proper visibility. This functionality is one of the must have in Lightning Experience but doesn't support formula fields with images in List Views.

Status Column with Image

[image: Status Icon column]

Formula Text field

```
IF(Status = "New", IMAGE("resource/statusIcon", "New"), "Closed")
```

Above formula works fine with Classic Interface but not for Lightning.

In lightning, it will displaying image Text("New") on list view.

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

maybe a bit outdated but please doublecheck that you use the / as first character in lightning. Instead of using

```
IMAGE("resource/statusIcon", "New")
```

please use

```
IMAGE("/resource/statusIcon", "New")
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the Salesforce documentation, you should be using Documents instead of static resources:

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000007604

Have you tried that?

Comment: It will not work whenever deployed from Sandbox to Production org. Because of Static ID `servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=0150a000002IK5H` from Document(Image). I've to maintain both the orgs with Static ID(0150a000002IK5H), whenever it required anything changes to IMAGE source. So, not helpful for best practices but perfect example of workaround. :)

Comment: You shouldn't hardcode the ID, use Custom Settings or Custom Metadata to store the ID on a per-org basis! :-)

Comment: Yes. I know. :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below formula and it is working for me both in lightning and classic.

```
IF(TEXT(Status) = "New", IMAGE('/resource/pkb_close_icon', 'NEW',44,44), "Closed")
```

Comment: Still not worked for me(above mentioned) in Lightning. Displaying text/value as **New** on formula column. Classic looks fine.

Comment: **Formula:** 

`IF(Time_With_Support__c = 0 && ISNULL(Time_With_Support__c), 'No Value', IF(Time_With_Support__c < 6 &&  NOT(ISNULL(Time_With_Support__c)), IMAGE('resource/viewedIcon', 'New',40,40), 'Closed'))` Note: _Time_With_Support__c_ is Number type field.

Comment: But in your formula the is no text called **New**.

Comment: Look 2nd IF Statement with **New** condition,  `IF(Time_With_Support__c < 6 && NOT(ISNULL(Time_With_Support__c)), IMAGE('resource/viewedIcon', 'New',40,40), 'Closed')` Whenever **Time_With_Support__c < 6** AND **NOT(ISNULL(Time_With_Support__c)** than `IMAGE('resource/viewedIcon', 'New',40,40)`

Comment: Have you checked with any other image? I can't any issues with the formula.

Comment: I've tried with this Document URL `/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015c00000003WAT`. Its working perfectly but through Static Resource image not working.

Comment: Try with another static resource to check if this issue is with this particular static resource file

Comment: Tried with several Static resource Images. Still no success.